# ANDROID STUDIO NÃO ATUALIZA

Tags: android, http, redes, proxy

Já fiz tudo no Android Studio e ele não atualiza e não o SDK update sites não consegue baixar o Android Repository, já vi que o erro é o 407, precisa de autenticação do proxy. Já configurei o proxy manualmente na aba HTTP, como o computador da empresa pede credencial, configurei já com a credencial, e no teste funciona, mas na hora de atualizar ou baixar algo não vai de jeito nenhum porque não tem autenticação, como faço para resolver isso?

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow. Veja se isso aqui ajuda: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49946565/8133067.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pelo erro 407 acusa que o Android Studio não consegue conectar porque não consegue conectar no proxy. Verifique com o Administrador da rede da empresa para você conseguir acessar o proxy e fazer a atualização, este erro ocorre para proteger a rede da empresa. Você pode ver mais sobre o erro 407 nesse [link](https://www.checkupdown.com/status/E407_pt.html) existe outra Thread aqui no Stack porem em inglês segue o [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16583394/android-studio-update-fails)